# Bind outside ItemsSource of DataTemplate, Windows phone

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

In my Windows Phone 8 I have LongListSelector and ItemTemplate specified for that. In code behind I set the ItemsSource for this LongListSelector.  In item template I want to bind value to outside ItemsSource. How to do that?

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="template">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding country}"/>
</DataTemplate>
...
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="list" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource template}">
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

C#

```c#
string country = "Japan";
this.list.ItemsSource = items;
```

So how to bind country to outside ItemsSource? The country is accessor  in my "code behind" phoneApplicationPage.

Comment: Where do you want the binding to go - on an item in the list or something outside of the list?

Comment: I what that the country value is coming outside the itemSource.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340176/binding-property-of-item-from-itemscontrol-to-value-outside-of-itemssource This is similar issue, but I think in Windows phone you can not use the same solution as RelativeSource AncestorType... is not supported in WP.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best that you make your models so that inside template you have to bind only to that item model.

Anyway it is possible to bind also outside of itemSource:

xaml:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>

            <!-- this binds to the layoutRoot's dataContext, which can be setted to be "code behind" -->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.Outside, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                            IsGroupingEnabled="False"
                            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}">

    </phone:LongListSelector>
</Grid>
```

In cs you have of course properties:

```
public ObservableCollection<Model> Items{get; set;}
public string Outside { get; set; }
```

Also layoutRoot's datacontext should be setted somewhere in cs:

```
LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
```